# Prolog sum all throwing error

Tags: recursion, prolog, sum

I have to write a predicates that sums all the items in a list. The items can be a list with list of list in it. for example, 
sum1([1,[2,3],4,[5]],X).
i have some code that SHOULD work, but is giving an arguments are not sufficiently instantiated error. I am very new to prolog but these look alright to me. here is my full code for this predicate (function)

```
suml([],0).
suml([H|T],X) :- atomic(H),S2 is H + X, suml(T,S2).
suml([H|T],X) :- suml(H,S1), S3 is S1 + X, suml(T,S3).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order of the following two conditions: `S2 is H + X, suml(T,S2)` and change the way you use `is/2`. Although this is logic programming, the order of the conditions in a rule matters. Put `sum1(T, S2)` first because you need `S2` to be instantiated before computing the sum. Second, `is` arithmetically evaluates the right part and unifies it with the left part. So, you actually want to sum `S2` and `H` to get `X`:

```
suml([H|T],X) :- atomic(H), suml(T,S2), X is H + S2.
```

Comment: Thank you again! i tried this second line, but it not working
suml([H|T],X) :- suml(T,X),suml(H,S1), S1 + X. basically this is saying if i have a list, sum that also and add it. but this is not working and im gettin undefined procedure

Comment: nvm! I had it wrong, I was confused by the X's in my own code because of how the instructor had examples.....i got it now, it should be suml([H|T],X) :- suml(T,S1),suml(H,S2), X is S1 + S2.